# Android Studio - External library folder not refresh

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I removed some **gradle** links from `build.gradle(app)` but removed libraries still showing in an **external library** folder.

Comment: delete library from both libs folder and build.gradle .

Comment: Tired but no luck.

Comment: Did you find any solution @ArunRavichandran ? I have got the same problem

Answer (score 8):

Go To Project Structure and select the module and go to dependency section and remove the library from the list if it exists.

If that doesn't work Go to File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the gradle caches directory, close and re-open Android Studio

rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way-:

Right Click on app under android->open module settings->dependencies->Then select the library you want to delete then press - button from right side of console.

Comment: It's  not showing the reference in open module settings but it's showing in external libraries folder this what an exact problem am facing. It keeps reference in external libraries folder.

Comment: go to project->libs->delete library or you can do is to to file folder where it is located i.e drive c or drive d and simply delete it from there